# jBoss AS 7.1 and LDAP auth - Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.LdapCtxFactory

Tags: java, jboss, ldap, jboss7.x

I'm trying to set up jBoss with LDAP auth. I have already configured the global module as follows:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
        <global-modules>
            <module name="sun.jdk" slot="main"/>
            <!--
             this no longer exists in AS 7.1
             <module name="com.sun.jndi.ldap" slot="main"/>
            -->
        </global-modules>
    </subsystem>
```

But I'm hitting this error when authenticating my web app.

```
16:17:56,505 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Login failure: ja
vax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:270) [picketbox-4.0.7.Fi
nal.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:4
49) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManage
r.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:3
71) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [
picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar
:]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:381) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:
7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-we
b-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final
.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.LdapCtxFactory from cla
ssloader null
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:664) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:134) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.constructInitialLdapContext(LdapExtLoginModule.java:655) [picketbox-4.0.
7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.createLdapInitContext(LdapExtLoginModule.java:436) [picketbox-4.0.7.Fina
l.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule.validatePassword(LdapExtLoginModule.java:312) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar
:4.0.7.Final]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:267) [picketbox-4.0.7.Fi
nal.jar:4.0.7.Final]
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: I have been trying the same out and I did comment the java.naming.factory.initial property as in your answer, but I still get the same error. I have created a jboss-web.xml that points to <security-domain>java:/jaas/LDAP</security-domain> besides the changes to the standalone.xml to configure LDAP. Is there anything else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `java.naming.factory.initial` property from my LDAP section of `standalone.xml` and everything works properly now.